# Delete Cache with UIWebview in an iOS application

Tags: html, ios, caching, uiwebview, request

I have a problem with UIWebview. I call several time an url for print a pictures in my webview and I count how many times my pictures was displayed.

When I call the url of the pictures the count match to the number of printing.

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url_pictures.com"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
[adView loadRequest:request];
```

When I call the url with loadhtmlstring my counter is to one. It's very important for me to use loadhtmlstring because my API returns me a html code with javascript.

```
NSString *html = @"<html><head></head><body>document.write(\"<a target=\"_blank\"ref=\"http://url_redirect.com\"><img border=\"0\" src=\"http://url_pictures.com\"></a>\");</body></html>";
NSString *baseURL = [mbAdUtil getBaseURL:html];
NSString *script = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", html];
[adView loadHTMLString:script baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseURL]];
```

I tested a lot of things that my counter is egal to printing.

this is some example of what I tested :

```
[webView loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:nil];
[webView stopLoading]; 
[webView setDelegate:nil];
[webView removeFromSuperview];
```

Another :

```
// remove all cached responses
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

// set an empty cache
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];

// remove the cache for a particular request
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeCachedResponseForRequest:request];
```

Also, I tested by destroying my instance of my project and create another.
I destroyed my webview, all my variable... and so much else that I can not remember.
My counter is always 1.

My better solution is :

```
[webView loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:nil];
[webView stopLoading]; 
[webView setDelegate:nil];
[webView removeFromSuperview];
```

With this I count 2 to 3 printing but the visual result is not that I expect.

Comment: how is your counting variable implemented?

Comment: my counting variable is in a database when I call the url, the database is incremented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem ! 
I remove all my tests and I added timestamp has all level :

```
NSString *html = @"<html><head></head><body>document.write(\"<a target=\"_blank\"ref=\"http://url_redirect.com?time = 123456789\"><img border=\"0\" src=\"http://url_pictures.com?time = 123456789\"></a>\");</body></html>";
```

NSString *baseURL = [mbAdUtil getBaseURL:html];

it same as if there were several level cache. It's very stange but it works...

My solution is :
if http://url_redirect.com or http://url_pictures.com call another url, we must add the timestamp for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add cache policy on NSURLRequest:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://url_pictures.com"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:10];
[adView loadRequest:request];
```

there three policy that will most likely help your solution:

- NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData,
- NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData,
- NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData

Comment: I want to use loadhtmlstring, not loadRequest. With loadRequest it works